# Proper way of notifying the application that DPDK received messages

Tags: intel, dpdk

currently, I'am using dpdk by sending and receiving the packets in to the rte-rings. I'am having difficulty of finding the proper way of to notify the application that the DPDK received incoming messages.

In order to check the whether the rte_ring has received the data or not, I run a busy loop on the rte_ring.
here is the example below

```
while (1) {
  if (rte_ring_dequeue(rx_ring, &_msg) < 0) {
    usleep(5);
  } else {
    recv_msg = (char *) _msg;
    if (chara_debug) printf("[%d] Server merge data::[%.24s...]__length::[%ld]\n", batched_packets, recv_msg, strlen(recv_msg));
    collect_packets++;
    if (collect_packets > MERGE_PACKETS) break;
  }
}
```

However, my fellow developers say that this is not a efficient way nor the proper way of checking received messages. Busy polling should be only done in the DPDK API and not in the application.

Is there a way for DPDK to send a signal to the application so that the application can only check the rte_ring only when there is a received message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, direct answer is to use DPDK event library: http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/eventdev.html

But it is not that smooth. Unless you have a hardware which directly supports the event model, you still need at least one RX core to poll (i.e. do the busy loop) as shown on this picture:
http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/eventdev.html#api-walk-through

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, in that case is the code above the correct way of using rte_ring for DPDK, On the premise that I am not using the event library?

Comment: It depends. If you can afford that sleep in data path — the code looks fine to me... Otherwise I would look into sched_yield(2) or even rte_pause().